# can Lubuntu install softwares for debian/redhat/suse/ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I have Lubuntu on my laptop. But when I'm looking to install something, under installation for Linux, there's only debian/redhat/suse/ubuntu. Would any of these be compatible with my Lubuntu OS?

Comment: Ubuntu packages are compatible with Lubuntu.

Comment: With regards to installing programs, Debian, Ubuntu and Lubuntu are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Software designed for Ubuntu is typically be compatible with Lubuntu. Red Hat and SUSE use a different package format altogether (RPM instead of DEB), so those packages won't be compatible with Lubuntu (or Ubuntu or Debian for that matter).

Comment: You have not said what type of programme you want to install; if you could be more specific someone on this forum could help. Do you have Synaptic installed? it does give you details of what is available and will assist you to install the programmes that you want from the compatible repositories.

Comment: @ys99x I assume you meant to comment on the question instead of this answer?